# Java Netbeans Drag Drop between modules

Tags: java, netbeans, drag-and-drop, widget, netbeans-platform

**Hi Internet!**

How can I move (drag&drop) one widget or an object from one module to another using the NetBeans Platform?

**EDIT:**

I need to move (DragAndDrop) an Image/JLabel from one TopComponent to Another TopComponent.
I can successfully move one image but I need and ID of that image, that I have as a text in the JLabel.
I have fail to implement a drag&drop for a JLabel and fail to implement a drag&drop for a JPanel with the JLabel inside.

If someone can offer hints, and pieces of code, anything is welcome.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at

- http://forums.netbeans.org/topic39500.html or
- https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/drag_a_node_from_a or
- https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/drag_a_node_from_a1

Comment: Thanks @Ben, the links gave me a general idea, but I'm still a little lost cause it isn't exactly my case and I'm having a hard time figuring it how to apply what's in those link to what I need.
But thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: What a pity that these links could not help you. 
Please provide a minimal example, more detailed questions and ask for help at dev@platform.netbeans.org. You can subscribe at http://netbeans.org/projects/platform/lists

Comment: Sorry @Ben I have started to find a way to make my program work, but I will edit my question to add more details to it. Maybe then I'll get more good answer like yours.